# PHP 5.1.4 not loading php_oci8.dll on Windows 10

Tags: php, oracle11g

When I want to login PHP to Oracle 11g in windows 10 it return null value. But in windows 7 xmlhttp.response and response text is true.Why php can not connect with oracle in windows 10?
Sample code for my login:

```
var url = "ajax_index.php?cStatus=chklogin&id="+form.id.value+"&passwd="+form.passwd.value; 
    xmlhttp = uzXmlHttp();
    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, false);        
    xmlhttp.send(null); 
    result = xmlhttp.responseText;
    if(result!="true"){
        if(result=="false"){
            alert('Invalid user/password ');
        }else{
            alert(result);
        }       
    }
```

and the connection is:

```
 $db="(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = XE)))";
$oracle_user="SFCORCLP";
$oracle_pwd="SFCORCLP";
```

This same code work fine in windows 7 but in windows 10 it always hits the else condition alert(result);